# Align different labels in a Tkinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, label

I have **x** labels, these are created using

```
rand = random.randint(1,100000)
local()[f'self.m{rand}'] = Label(self.frame, text='test')
local()[f'self.m{rand}'].pack()
```

Furthermore I have a frame, I want to set a label next to another one following this scheme

```
Label 1 Label 2

Label 3 Label 4

Label 5 Label 6

Label **y** Label **x**
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could proceed?

Comment: instead of using `locals()` better use dictionary to keep elements.

Comment: to create columns and rows use `grid()` instead of `pack()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grid()` instead of `pack()` to create columns and rows.

If you use `pack()` then create `Frame` using `pack()` and then inside `Frame` you can use `grid()`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

labels = {}

for row_number in range(5):
    for col_number in range(2):
        value = 1 + row_number*2 + col_number
        labels[value] = tk.Label(frame, text='Label ' + str(value))
        labels[value].grid(row=row_number, column=col_number)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: There is a way to do this with .pack() ? I have already slaves managed by pack

Comment: you can't create it with `pack()` - but you can create frame using `pack()` and then inside frame you can use `grid()`.